# DateTime object cloning Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in Magento Model

Tags: php, magento

I just encountered strange thing going on while working on custom Magento Model.

Model is called as singleton and works:

While trying to clone object property **second** time it results in fatal error.

```
function someFunction1() {
     $datetime_from = clone $this->from;

}
```

On the other hand, this function:

```
function someFunction2() {
    echo '<pre>'.__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.'<br>';
    var_export(gettype($this->from));
    echo '</pre>';
    $datetime_from = clone $this->from;
}
```

results in:

> ...\Model\Data.php:230
>
> 'object'
>
> true
>
> Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in
>   Q:\magento\app\code\local\Tece\Goals\Model\Data.php on line 235

Answer (score 1):

Same problem: I was cloning a `DateTime` object in a loop, debug showed it was fine, but cloning still failed. Turns out the variable got cleared in subsequent iterations, and cloning failed because of that.

However, while researching, I found [Do You Clone the DateTime Objects?](http://axiac.ro/blog/dont-forget-to-clone-the-datetime-objects/).

Here's the main point:

> Since PHP 5.5 it’s better to use [DateTimeImmutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) objects whenever it’s possible. They cannot be modified after they are created (they behave like true Value Objects). The methods declared in DateTimeInterface that modify the DateTime objects automatically create and return clones for DateTimeImmutable objects.

That way there's no need to clone at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this.

The object I was trying to clone was a string, was just other variable, other line number.

Hardest is to find the bug that doesn't exist.